# Where's the chess board?

Tags: support

I can't seem to find where to play chess at this site. Am I missing something or is it not available, only Q&A here?

Comment: No educational comment offered. Just an autonomous negative drive-by? A simple answer would would be less rude.

Comment: You cannot play chess here only ask questions and answer questions.

Comment: Thankyou for the clarification Akavail. I normally play online chess at Gameknot. Someone suggested checking this site but it's now obvious that they meant for chess data, not games.

Comment: http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/170/anyone-want-to-meet-in-chat-and-play-some-online-blitz lets play and get with some ideas

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a chess board here, since we're a Q&A site, not a game client. Check out our [about page](https://chess.stackexchange.com/about) to get a grasp of the features of Stack Exchange.